# Flutter InternalLinkedHashMap cast error only when context has been restored

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I'm building an app in Flutter and I'm trying to allow my pages to be restorable, even though some arguments are passed to those pages.

My code:

Main:

```
child: MaterialApp(
  restorationScopeId: 'root_app',
  onGenerateRoute: Routes.buildRoutes(),
  title: 'My App',
  theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.teal),
)
```

Routing:

```
static RouteFactory buildRoutes() {
  return (settings) {
    final arguments = settings.arguments != null ? settings.arguments as Map<String, dynamic> : <String, dynamic>{};
    Widget _view;

    var route = findRoute(settings.name);
    switch (route) {
      case Routes.menu:
        _view = const Menu();
        break;
      case Routes.selection:
        _view = const Page2(arguments);
        break;
      default:
        return null;
    }

    return MaterialPageRoute(
        settings: settings,
        builder: (context) => RestorationScope(restorationId: route.restorationId, child: _view),
    );
  };
}
```

Navigation:

```
onSuccess: (List<Map<String, dynamic>> evalData) =>
  Navigator.restorablePushReplacementNamed(context, widget._route.value, arguments: <String, dynamic>{'data': evalData}),
```

When I run the following code for the first time (not from a restoration, but by navigation) I get NO errors and my page loads normally.

When I put the app in the background (with don't keep alive) and bring it back, forcing a restoration, I get a "_InternalLinkedHashMap cast" error and the debugger data is as follows:

[image]

[image]

It's interesting to note that the data itself is pushed and works the first time, being passed by navigation. But when this data is restored (correctly according to the debugger) I get an error while trying to cast it.

I did found something similar at [Github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/79376) and also this is a version working thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71874339/using-ongenerateroute-with-restorationscope) by @pskink

I also decided to raise an [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/102579) at Flutter's github.

Comment: I've also tried: `Map<String, dynamic>.from(settings.arguments as Map)`